# How to replace the first character alone in a string using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace

**How to replace the first character alone in a string using python?**

```
string = "11234"
translation_table = str.maketrans({'1': 'I'})
output= (string.translate(translation_table))
print(output)
```

**Expected Output:**

```
I1234
```

**Actual Ouptut:**

```
11234
```

Comment: can't you just do something like `'I' + string[1:] `?

Comment: Note: Your "Got Output" should be `II234`, not `11234`, unless you're saying `translate` did nothing. I copied and pasted the code and got `II234` as expected.

Comment: I find this question confusing, and all the answers below incorrect if I interpret "first character" as the first character of the string, not the first matching character. The solutions provided would replace "21234" with "2I234", which is not  the first character of the string. The OP's intention is ambiguous because they selected one of the incorrect answers as the right one. Can you clarify whether you intended "first character" or "first occurrence"?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf your solution would work but only with a condition, otherwise it would replace any character with `I`, and the OP specified a translation table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Python, strings are immutable meaning you cannot assign to indices or modify a character at a specific index. Use [str.replace()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) instead. Here's the function header

```
str.replace(old, new[, count])
```

This built in function returns a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring *old* replaced by *new*. If the optional argument *count* is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.

If you don't want to use `str.replace()`, you can manually do it by taking advantage of splicing

```
def manual_replace(s, char, index):
    return s[:index] + char + s[index +1:]

string = '11234'
print(manual_replace(string, 'I', 0))
```

Output

> I1234

Comment: this answer basically is very similar to mine just that this provides a references to that method....

Answer (score 15):

I am not sure what you want to achive, but it seems you just want to replace a `'1'` for an `'I'` just once, so try this:

```
string = "11234"
string.replace('1', 'I', 1)
```

`str.replace` takes 3 parameters `old`, `new`, and `count` (which is optional). `count` indicates  the number of times you want to replace the `old` substring with the `new` substring.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `re` (regex), and use the `sub` function there, first parameter is the thing you want to replace, and second is the thing that you want to replace with, third is the string, fourth is the count, so i say `1` because you only want the first one:

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "11234"
>>> re.sub('1', 'I', string, 1)
'I1234'
>>>
```

It's virtually just:

```
re.sub('1', 'I', string, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

by reading your question, I understand you want to replace a certain character of your sting on a certain index, in your case replace character on index [0] with 'I',

my answer:

well as we know string's are immutable so we cannot just modify and replace a character directly, **but** their is a way to go around this,
steps:

1. convert your string into a list
2. change the character on specified index
3. convert back into a sting

code:

```
string = "11234"
string_asList = list(string)       #converts sting into list

string_asList[0] = "I"             #replace element at [O] index
string = ''.join(string_asList)    #converts list back to string

print(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am interpreting the OP's "first character" correctly, this should replace the first and only the first character of the string if matching:

```py
string = "11234"
translation_table = str.maketrans({'1': 'I'})
output = string[0].translate(translation_table) + string[1:]
print(output)
```